# Error when refreshing data from external source in excel. Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, odbc

I have an excel workbook which has an external data source to create a pivot table. This file was sent to me. I can open it up correctly, but when I try to refresh the data I get the following error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.
```

As far as I'm concerned, Windows should use the default ODBC driver (odbcad.exe) for the connection. Any idea what might be causing the error when refreshing the data?

EDIT: 
The connection string has DSN, UID, TRUSTED_CONNECTION, APP, WSID and DATABASE fields.

EDIT: I set up the ODBC connection, but now I'm getting the following error:

```
[ODBC Driver Manager] The Specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even thought the ODBC connection information is present in the Excel workbook, an ODBC connection must be established between your PC and the data source in order for the workbook to connect.

Not sure what OS you are using, but here is [Using the ODBC Data Source Administrator](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Using-the-ODBC-Data-Source-Administrator) for Windows 7.

If you do not know the information to setup the connection, contact your network administrator.

Comment: The ODBC is now connected but it's throwing another error when refreshing the data. It's on the original post.

Comment: It has to do with the use of 64 bit vs 32 bit drivers. If the data sources is 32 bit, you must use a 32 bit driver when you set up the local ODBC connection. Here is MSDN information on the additional error: [Managing Data Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms712362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)